# C# LINQ is taking DataTable AsEnumerable and changing the column datatype

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datatable, enumerable

I am trying to retrieve a row from a DataTable using LINQ.
Prior to the LINQ query the column datatype is System.String.
Running the LINQ query results in a 'Invalid Cast Exception' and shows that the column datatype is System.Double.

How do I get the AsEnumerable or LINQ to keep the datatype as string?

1. I create the DataTable by retrieving from the database:

   ```
   DataTable dt1 = ld.GetInventory();
   ViewState["dt1"] = dt1;
   ```
2. I confirm the datatype:

   ```
   var type = ((DataTable)ViewState["dt1"]).Columns["Part"].DataType;
   ```

The returned value is: **System.String**

2. I then LINQ the datatable:

   ```
    var results = from myRow in ((DataTable)ViewState["dt1"]).AsEnumerable()
             where myRow.Field<string>("Part") == part
             select myRow;
   ```

**Update 1: StackTrace**

```
    [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.]
    System.Data.UnboxT`1.ReferenceField(Object value) +60
    System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow row, String columnName) +77
    History.<>c__DisplayClass1.<gvInventory_SelectedIndexChanging>b__0(DataRow myRow) in c:\History\InventoryReport.aspx.cs:182
    System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +139
    History.InventoryReport.gvInventory_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender,               GridViewSelectEventArgs e) in c:\History\InventoryReport.aspx.cs:191
         System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnSelectedIndexChanging(GridViewSelectEventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSelect(Int32 rowIndex) +43
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +213
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +201
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl,  String eventArgument) +13
      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9664310
      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `myRow.Field<string>("Part")`? I can't even compile without the type parameter. Can you please show the exact code?

Comment: @RenéVogt - you are correct.  The question wasn't formatted correctly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour. (Created a `DataTable` with a column `"Part"` of type `string`, added a `DataRow` with that column set to `"1.2"` and executed your linq query... everything worked fine)

Comment: LINQ isn't changing anything. If there's a problem, it's because either `part` is double or the column. Or the error actually occurs in a different line. Please post the complete exception, including its stack trace

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the stack trace has been added.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `part` must be `string`, otherwise this code would not compile.

Comment: This code works fine even if you really add `double` values to the column. So the only reason I can see would be that your type checking is telling you something wrong. This exception with this stack trace can only happen if the `DataType` of the column is `double`.

Comment: @RenéVogt - i agree that the type checking isn't being truthful.  I found a workaround by using myRow.Field<object>("Part").ToString()

Comment: Checking the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs,8fc340fe81663576) where the error occurs, it realy is trying to cast the column's value to a string and failing. Which means that something *is* wrong with the type checking code. What does `.DataType` return?

Comment: Well but there seems to be something wrong if that column is not of the type you expected. So hiding that error by using `Field<object>` may not be the best solution.

Comment: @JohnM that's no workaround, that's covering up the problem. Your column's type is `double`. You should check (and post here) the code you are using to *create* the datatable and *check* the type, not assume that the DataTable is wrong - it isn't.

Comment: In fact, `ReferenceField` is only called if the column's type is a reference type. Have you loaded doubles wrapped as objects? Please post a **reproducible example**

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have included the datatable creation code -> it's done mostly 'automatically'

Comment: Post the code *inside* `GetInvontory`. What does "automatically" mean? Is the DataTable loaded from a database table? What is the underlying field's type?

Comment: Part is nvarchar, there might be another field (not shown) that is causing issue -> it's float.  I am testing now.